# playframework combinators documentation raises error: not found - why?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

when I try out the first example in the documentation of combinators http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonCombinators then it raises errors in the repl and not found value with a scala file within a play app (tried with play 2.2.0 and play 2.1.1) - trace back from the repl:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

val customReads: Reads[(String, Float, List[String])] = 
  (JsPath \ "key1").read[String](email keepAnd minLength(5)) and 
  (JsPath \ "key2").read[Float](min(45)) and
  (JsPath \ "key3").read[List[String]] 
  tupled


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:16: error: not found: value tupled
        tupled
        ^
<console>:11: error: not found: value email
        (JsPath \ "key1").read[String](email keepAnd minLength(5)) and 
                       ^

scala>
```

well how to solve that ?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems.  First, you need one more import:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
```

Second, the doc was written likely before functions like "minLength" and "min" were made generic, to handle more than just String and Float.  So you have to specify the types for those:

```
val customReads: Reads[(String, Float, List[String])] =
    (JsPath \ "key1").read[String](email keepAnd minLength[String](5)) and
    (JsPath \ "key2").read[Float](min[Float](45)) and
    (JsPath \ "key3").read[List[String]]
    tupled
```

This was the discussion I read that I found informative in regards to this:

[play-framework Google Group Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/play-framework/error%243A%2420diverging%2420implicit%2420expansion%2420for%2420type%2420play.api.libs.json.Reads%5BM%5D/play-framework/WIPTtpTTvg0/5uypp-p8TuAJ)

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation and pointer to the "play-framework Google Group Discussion"